# Spacing in java array output

Tags: java, arrays, runtime-error

Im having problems with my code. I was asked to create a parallel array using a txt which contained morse code and like values. Ex: A .-
                                          B -...
etc...

Heres where my error is-

```
public class Translate
{
String input;
String code[];
String alphabet[];

public Translate(String input)
{
    this.input = input;
}

public void setInput(String input)
{
    this.input = input;
}

public void setAlph(String[] alphabet)
{
    this.alphabet = alphabet;
}

public void setCode(String[] code)
{
    this.code = code;
}

public String getInput()
{
    return input;
}

public String getTranslate()
{
    String output = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
    {
        for(int index = 0; index < alphabet.length; index++)
        {
            if(input.charAt(i) == alphabet[index].charAt(0)
            {
                output = output + code[index];
            }
        }
    }
return output;
}
}
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 36

I usually dont ask for help but I've been on this for a few hours.
The only way I can see to compare the input.charAt with the alphabet(string) is to parse the string into a char or to add the .charAt at the end. I've tried doing alphabet[index].charAt(index)) but that did not work either. it gave me the same error only with 1 not 36

UPD Im getting the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at Translate.getTranslate(Translate.java:39)"

UPD No longer receiving errors. I am however confused on my next task. I'm required to add one space between more code letters and 3 spaces between words. 
Ex: If "Hey" is user input the output should be ".... . -.-- " compared to what Im receiving ".....-.--"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `index <= alphabet.length` should be `index < alphabet.length`.  I think you have other problems, though - a more complete problem statement would help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is `for(int index = 0; index <= alphabet.length; index++)` - you keep incrementing `index` until it's equal to the length of the alphabet, which will make it overshoot the end giving the exception you're getting. You should make it `index < alphabet.length` to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

You did not show all variable declarations and sample input so the following is based on my guess about them.

1. What looks strange is "<=", should be "<"

   for(int index = 0; index <= alphabet.length; index++)
2. You should not iterate over alphabet each time but prepare the mapping beforehand. That would be more efficient.

Comment: I updated it with more information. I changed the "<=" to "<" and now Im getting the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Translate.getTranslate(Translate.java:39)" @Animatinator

Comment: Now alphabet[index] is null, right? The error should be straightforward to debug with some IDE. If you need further help we need to know "input" value, Arrays.toString(alphabet) and  Arrays.toString(code).